# Blazor change input number value in different cultures

Tags: input, localization, blazor, cultureinfo

I have an input like this

```
<input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" value="@person.G" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs e) => G_changed(e, person))">
```

And I want to change person.G value and use it in order to recalculate variable in the following function

```
private async Task G_Changed(ChangeEventArgs e, Person person)
{
    person.G = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    person.D = await GetLIGE(person.G);        
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

I have a multi language site and it works when the input type is a text but not if I make it a number.

I prefer to have the input type as number in order to limit the user in order to insert only numbers and not text

**Edit:**

The problem is that when I change language to Greek then the numbers get "," as decimal number separator.
For Example 10.1 is transformed to 10,1.
And then I get multiple troubles in calculations including that it cannot increase values in input number with step.

So, the solution it may be to keep the dot (10.1) decimal separator even if the culture is set to Greek.
How can I do this? Any idea?

Comment: I'm confused.  What culture doesn't use numbers?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - I don't think the issue has anything to do with culture.

Comment: I don't think so either, so I'm confused what specific culture-related issue the OP thinks he has.  Is it something about entering curency amounts or something?  I can see how entering Korean Won, which has no decimals, and USD, which does, might make things difficult.

Comment: Please check again I edited my text

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided enough code or context here's a demo page showing updating working:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="m-2">
    <h4>Net6.0+</h4>
    @foreach (var model in _models)
    {
        <label class="form-label small">@model.Country</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control mb-3"
               value="@model.Value"
           @onchange="(e) => On6Change(e, model)" />
    }
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <h4>Net7.0+</h4>
    @foreach (var model in _models)
    {
        <label class="form-label small">@model.Country</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control mb-3"
           @bind:get=model.Value
           @bind:set="(value) => On7Change(value, model)" />
    }
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    @foreach (var model in _models)
    {
        <pre>@model.Country Population : @model.Value</pre>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<Model> _models = new()
    {
        new(){ Country="France", Value = 46.1 },
        new(){ Country="Spain", Value = 67.4 },
    };

    private async Task On6Change(ChangeEventArgs e, Model country)
    {
        // Fake doing some async work
        await Task.Yield();
        country.Value = double.Parse((e.Value?.ToString() ?? "0"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private async Task On7Change(double value, Model country)
    {
        // Fake doing some async work
        await Task.Yield();
        country.Value = value;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Country { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```